# Does Heimdall have the option to boot without flashing/substituting the kernel? (like fastboot boot boot.img)

Tags: fastboot, rom, kernel, heimdall

Fastboot has the option `fastboot boot Image.gz` to boot a kernel without flashing it to the phone. Is there something similar for Heimdall? I did not want to mess with my phone's kernel for now. It's a Galaxy A50.

By the way, what is the "no reboot" button for?

Comment: Buttons on heimdall?

Comment: @alecxs on the frontend for it, or the command line